# SQL: Find names of sailors who made at least 3 reservations

Tags: sql

So I have this table:

```
Sailors (sid, sname, rating, age)
Boats (bid, bname, color)
Reserves (sid, bid, date)
```

The query that I thought would do it is:

```
SELECT Sailors.sname
FROM Sailors, Reserves
WHERE 3 <= COUNT(Reserves.sid = Sailor.sid)
```

I know this solution doesn't work, but I'm not sure how to do it other than this. I'm a complete beginner in SQL, so if you could explain any code that you type, that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this-

```
 SELECT Sailors.sname
 FROM Sailors
 JOIN Reserves
 ON Sailors.sid = Reserves.sid
 GROUP BY Sailors.name
 HAVING count(Reserves.bid) >= 3;
```

EDIT : The logic above aggregates at the sailor name level/granularity (using group by clause) so that the number of reservations can be counted at an aggregate level for each sailor and then uses having clause which is used for aggregate comparisons to check the given criteria of the number of reservations at the sailor level

Comment: On JOIN Reserves you could use USING as the fields has the same name `sid`. JOIN Reserves USING(sid).

Comment: Could you explain the logic of this?

Comment: Agreed, but I generally like to stick with this syntax as it is more generic.

Comment: @MarchinDelta - Added the explanation of the logic in my response.